# Check in Hosted Web App if location permission is granted

Tags: web-applications, location, windows-10-universal

I have a simple Windows10 Web App, generated by the MS Appstudio https://appstudio.windows.com/ => "Hosted Web App".
The app only use a "Package.appxmanifest" and load an mobile optimized website.

In the Web App I use the .
Is it possible to integrate the "Change the location privacy settings" function from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/get-location ?

```
<!--Set Visibility to Visible when access to location is denied -->  
<TextBlock x:Name="LocationDisabledMessage" FontStyle="Italic"
                 Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="0,15,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" >
          <Run Text="This app is not able to access Location. Go to " />
              <Hyperlink NavigateUri="ms-settings:privacy-location">
                  <Run Text="Settings" />
              </Hyperlink>
          <Run Text=" to check the location privacy settings."/>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the Web App I use the . Is it possible to integrate the "Change the location privacy settings" function from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/get-location ?

For your scenario you could integrate the "Change the location privacy settings" function by using java-scrip Api in your html page. You could reference the following code to launch `privacy-location`.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>LunchUriTest</title>
    <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>Content goes here!</div>
    <button id="btnClick">Clik Me</button>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Main.js**

```
(function () {
    document.querySelector("#btnClick").onclick = function () {
        if (typeof (Windows) != "undefined") {
            var uri = Windows.Foundation.Uri("ms-settings:privacy-location")
            Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(uri);
        } else {
            alert("Current environment is not uwp ")
        }
    }
})();
```